# SQL TEST: OUTER JOIN a prod tbl & compOrder tbls. Display id & prodname frm product tbl, display id & totAmt fr compOrder tbl where both tbl id<10

Tags: mysql, outer-join

I have a prod table and compOrder table. I need to Perform an OUTER JOIN on the product and completedOrder tables.
Display the id and productname from the product table and the id and totalAmount from the completedOrder table where the id is less than 10 in both tables.

This is what I have thus far. I'm New, learning and need guidance. Thanks in advance - amanda

```
SELECT product.id, 
       product.productName, 
       completedOrder.id, 
       completedOrder.totalAmount
FROM completedOrder
FULL JOIN product
    ON product.id < '10' = completedOrder.id < '10'
ORDER BY productName;
```

Comment: MySQL does not support FULL JOIN. ON clause must set joining condition, not filtering conditions which must be placed to WHERE clause.

Comment: SELECT product.id, product.productName, completedOrder.id, completedOrder.totalAmount
    FROM completedOrder
    LEFT JOIN product 
    ON product.id = completedOrder.id
    WHERE product.id < '10' AND completedOrder.id < '10'
    ORDER BY product.id;

Comment: Remember to treat integers as integers. Don't assume that the optimiser will know what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

You use 2 tables prod and compOrder. What is the relationship between both table?.
Let us assume product.id is in compOrder table as product_id[foreign key].
You have to change your query like this,

```
    SELECT p.id, p.productName, c.id,c.totalAmount
    FROM completedOrder as c
    JOIN product as p
    ON p.id=c.product_id
    WHERE p.id < '10' AND c.id < '10'
    ORDER BY p.productName;
```

Comment: Thank you. This gave me my missing pieces.
SELECT product.id, product.productName, completedOrder.id, completedOrder.totalAmount
    FROM completedOrder
    LEFT JOIN product 
    ON product.id = completedOrder.id
    WHERE product.id < '10' AND completedOrder.id < '10'
    ORDER BY product.id;